# How do I customize the shell in Multipass (on Ubuntu)?

Tags: 20.10, multipass

I am running Groovy Gorilla, and have installed Multipass for a dev environment.  While reading how-to docs, I've seen different setups for the shell (larger font, different font colors, etc).

How do I customize the shell?  In particular, I need to increase the font size because it's tiny.  tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a similar issue when using the multipass terminal. But you can simply avoid using the multipass shell by using your default terminal and type `multipass shell <your VM name>`.

There are quite a lot of useful commands of multipass, you can try `multipass help`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I was trying to avoid that because I wanted to keep coding vs non-coding tasks compartmentalized.  I ended up using my regular terminal.